# pip works for python2.7 but not 3.5

Tags: python, linux, pip, fedora, pyperclip

I'll start by saying I am a complete novice and am likely overlooking something obvious. Don't assume I have any idea about anything related to linux or python.

Anyway, I installed python 3.5 onto my computer which runs Fedora 23. Fedora comes prepackaged with 2.7. When I installed 3.5, I somehow installed it into my /home/user/Documents directory. I since deleted that `rm -r -f /home/user/Documents/Python-3.5.1` directory. Yet I can still open 3.5 when I type `python3`. Originally I created an alias to point to the python command in the home/user/Documents/Python-3.5.1 directory, so being able to still open 3.5 after deleting that directory and removing the alias is confusing, and must mean I had two python 3.5 installs. That's some backstory that isn't really my problem, but maybe it's related.

The issue I'm having is that I cannot install a module that I want to import for use in a Python 3.5 program.

When I type `pip install pyperclip` (I'm working through AutomateTheBoringStuff) pyperclip is installed for 2.7. If I open the python2.7 command line and type `import pyperclip` everything is fine, but if I try the same thing in the python3.5 command line I get an error saying the module does not exist.

I assume this is because pip installs the pyperclip module to the subdirectories associated with 2.7. How can I install modules for 3.5 using pip?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Fedora does things, but in Debian/Ubuntu, we get the `pip3` command to use pip with Python 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for replying Tom. Here's what I tried:

`pip3 install pyperclip`

`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyperclip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `python3 -m pip install pyperclip`

Comment: Hi Red. Here's what I tried: `python3 -m pip install pyperclip`
The computer replied:
`/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Comment: you not have installed pip for python3. use `dnf install python3-pip`

Comment: Here's what I tried: `sudo dnf install python3-pip`


Here's what I got: `Last metadata expiration check: 1:22:23 ago on Sun May 22 07:26:50 2016.
Package python3-pip-7.1.0-1.fc23.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
`

Comment: plz execute `python3 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"` and show results.

Comment: Hey Red, thanks for your attention to my issue. I really appreciate you taking your time out to help me.

Here's what I did: `python3 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"`

Here's what I got: `['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages']`

Comment: Check if a directory exists `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip`.
better `ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip`

Comment: Red, I got all the way to "site-packages". That was an empty directory other than a README file.

The pip directory was absent.

Comment: please execute `python3 -m pip -v list` and show results. probably better use pastebin.com

Comment: you forgot `-v` option

Comment: I did something worse actually. I typed: `python -m pip -v list` which gave the output you saw. I just redid your instruction.

I typed: `python3 -m pip -v list`

I got: `/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Comment: yeah. look like you have python3-pip installed to wrong directory.
give me plz result of `rpm -ql python3-pip` . 
try `dnf reinstall python3-pip` and check  `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip`

Comment: Here is the gigantic output: http://pastebin.com/aRtKZzYg
I tried reinstalling, and then I checked `usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip` but there was nothing in `site-packages` except a README file.

Comment: ough. you have python 3.4 installed with 3.5. how you install 3.5 ?

Comment: I have no idea what I did to get to this point. I suppose I didnt' realize 3.4 was capable of what I wanted to do, so I'm just going to ignore python3.5 on my machine.

I just: `alias python='usr/bin/python3.4'`

That will be good enough. Thank you for all of your help. You really assisted me in better understanding the situation. Though we couldn't get 3.5 to behave, I realize I can just use 3.4 instead.

Again thank you for your attention. I'll mark this solved.

Comment: you have 3 options
 1. move to fedora 24 with shipped python 35 for evading problem in future (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_package_manager?rd=Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum);
 2. remove python3.5 and use 3.4. ;
 3. install python3-pip ( for python 3.5);

Good luck.